# Deploying Ionic app to the Google store

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework

I'm trying to deploy my first (very generic) app built using Ionic. According to the [docs for deployment](https://ionicframework.com/docs/pro/deploy/), I'm supposed to use some plugins. However, other sources suggest that I'm supposed to install Google's IDE called Android Studio and create an APK file.

I can't judge which approach is most valid nor if the one is an obsoleted version of the other. And we know how fast the wheels rotate in JS world...

NB. I'm confident in programming in general, I know Angular and have experience with deployments as such. In this case, I'm not looking to set up CI nor testing. I simply want my first app to be reachable through the store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to make a build: `ionic cordova build android`. Next sign it using the command line. 
https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html

Comment: So you're not in favor of the Ionic Pro Tools they're promoting heavily on the website? After signing, would you suggest that I use Android Studio and build the project as [described here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/deploying/)? Please keep in mind that when it comes to apps and Android, I'm a total noob.

Comment: Usually i'm not in favour of anything called "Pro" :P. I would indeed follow that documentation. You don't need Android Studio because the Android sdk is already somewhere (it is used by ionic). You can use the keytool from your commandline. However, it might me easier to create a keystore with Android Studio if you haven;t one already.

Comment: All right - the question is kind of answered, so check and +1. However, I got stuck on *gradlew assembleRelease* which apparently isn't recognized in the console of the IDE and I have **waaaay** to little competence within Java and its tools to start fighting the issue. I got as far as to obtain the key. Then, the guide stopped being coherent with my computer.

Comment: You won't need to run that because `ionic cordova build android` generates the unsigned apk.

Comment: Right! I've been googling it and reading on. Apparently, I don't need Android Studio at all - I can go CLI and use console like a normal person. Awesome! I already asked a new question as I can't get the version of JDK to be found by Cordova, so I'm getting forth, although slowly. Thanks!